# How can I iterate through an ArrayList of the different class objects to search for a specific class?

Tags: java, oop, arraylist

How can I iterate through an ArrayList of the different class objects to search for a specific class?

productionDate is an interface that is implemented in base classes.

Here is the code but it doesn't print anything :)

```
ArrayList<ProductionDate> storage;

public void search(Class c, int itemCount){
   if(storage.getClass() == c){
       for(ProductionDate d : storage){
           if(d instanceof ProductionDate &&
                   ((ProductionDate)d).getItemCount() >= itemCount){
                     System.out.println(d);
           }
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: I suggest adding `System.out.println()` statements to debug this. [This article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) has some more tips for debugging your code.

Comment: Could you share your main method as well?

Comment: Note that `d instanceof ProductionDate` will always be true because you declare `ProductionDate d`.

Comment: When you say "search for a specific class" do you really mean "search for a specific object"?

Comment: And what is the purpose of `if(storage.getClass() == c)`? What are you passing as the first parameter to `search()`>

Comment: I want to pass a class for example search(A.class, 12) that implements the ProductionDate interface, So how am I supposed to print that specific object?

Comment: Please edit your question to show a [mcve] that we can compile and run ourselves. You are clearly making this more complicated than necessary. If `ProductionDate` already declares `getItemCount()` then this can be made much simpler by leveraging polymorphism.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice `d` could be null.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- Good point. In that case would `d instanceof ProductionDate` be `false`? Even so, `d == null` or `d != null` would be a better condition to use.

Answer (score 0):

First, Remove the first if statement.

Secondly, You should use the class that implements ProductionDate interface in order to check whether the object belongs to that specific class. I think that class is `Class c` here.

So:

```
ArrayList<ProductionDate> storage;

public void search(Class c, int itemCount){
    for(ProductionDate d : storage){
           if(d instanceof c &&
                   ((c)d).getItemCount() >= itemCount){
                     System.out.println(d);
           }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this is the right direction. Also, if `ProductionDate` already declares `getItemCount()` you can remove `d instanceof c` and the cast.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how you call the method, but this works:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Object> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    Class c = arrayList.getClass();
    search(c, 12);
}

public static void search(Class c, int itemCount) {
    ArrayList<ProductionDate> storage = new ArrayList<>();
    storage.add(new ProductionDate(13));
    storage.add(new ProductionDate(15));
    storage.add(new ProductionDate(11));

    if (storage.getClass() == c) {
        for (ProductionDate d : storage) {
            if (d instanceof ProductionDate &&
                    ((ProductionDate) d).getItemCount() >= itemCount) {
                System.out.println(d);
            }
        }
    }
}


private static class ProductionDate {
    int itemCount;

    public ProductionDate(int itemCount) {
        this.itemCount = itemCount;
    }

    public int getItemCount() {
        return itemCount;
    }

}
```

}

output:

```
Main$ProductionDate@5acf9800
Main$ProductionDate@4617c264
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).